# What are the advantages of Zigbee over Bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, zigbee

What are the advantages of Zigbee over Bluetooth? I have only been able to find this advantage:

> It is flexibly expandable and passes on commands that are not intended
> for this device. It therefore spans a network (mesh network) over all
> known Smart Home devices. This means that the range can be increased
> with each additional device

but why should I use Zigbee instead of Bluetooth?
With Bluetooth, I can form piconets, so theoretically I can also increase the range, right?
A scatternet is formed from several piconets and enables communication between the piconets using bridge nodes.

So what are the advantages of Zigbee over Bluetooth?

Answer (score 5):

Zigbee must survive 2 yr battery life with low power, low bit rate.

Bluetooth must support smooth streaming audio which was the original market.

These are exclusive requirements.

Comment: You’re overlooking BLE, which in many use cases competes directly with Zigbee.

Comment: That's true  Zigbee is far less popular as a result but still alive   https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Comparison_of_802.15.4_radio_modules

Answer (score 3):

For one, Zigbee is EASY. Zigbee trades speed for range, power, and ease of use.

> "*With Bluetooth, I can form piconets, so theoretically I can also increase the range, right*"

You can try, but with the right Zigbee you can just blast a signal 40km, and then you can mesh on top of that to extend range. You won't find it practical to use 4001 Bluetooth nodes to pass the signal along every 10m for 40km.

Even without anything special, a Zigbee often works at about a dozen times distance of Bluetooth.